# read data from socket in server thread using sockets

Tags: java, sockets, server

The application has client and server threads. The client thread is working properly.
There is a problem during reading from the server what the client on the other application is sending to mine application.

There is two requirements to implement this server

1. I need to use UTF-16LE encoding
2. I cannot use readLine, I need only to use read byte/s

I tried many examples but nothing seems to work properly.

Here is the code of the server

```
private static final int    NUM_STATUSES    = 30;
private static final int    NUM_ERRORES     = 50;
private ServerSocket        _serverSocket;
private Socket              _socket;
private Handler             _handler;
private int                 _port;

//handler of main activity
public ServerNetworkThread()
{
    setName("ServerNetworkThread");
}

public void setHandler(Handler h)
{
    _handler = h;
}

@Override
public void run()
{

    _isWorking = true;
    try
    {
        _serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
        _serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        _serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(_port));

        while (_isWorking)
        {
            _socket = _serverSocket.accept();
            _socket.setSoTimeout(Consts.CLIENT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

            readDataTest();

        }

    }
    catch (SocketTimeoutException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void readDataTest() throws IOException
{
    //          BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_socket.getInputStream(),Charset.forName("UTF-16LE")));
    InputStream iStream = _socket.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(iStream, Charset.forName("UTF-16LE"));
    DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(_socket.getOutputStream());
    char[] buf = new char[iStream.available()];
    in.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
    String request = new String(buf);

    String responseStr = parseResponse(request);
    byte[] response = responseStr.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
    outToClient.write(response);
    outToClient.flush();
    outToClient.close();
    in.close();
    _socket.close();
    //          inFromClient.close();
}
```

Sometimes I am receiving a timeout when I am attempting to read the data the server receives from the client.

Thanks for your help

Comment: could you post the stacktrace?

Comment: After printing what I am receiving I noticed something strange:
request=BB0006<ENDL>0011<EOF>└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א
there are many characters at the end that don't need to be there, maybe there is a problem with line
char[] buf = new char[iStream.available()];

Comment: In `String request = new String(buf);` you are building a string using UTF-8 with bytes comming from UTF-16L. Specify the charset when constructing that string

Comment: There is no String constructor that can get char [] with encoding, how can I fix this?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset)

Comment: One big problem you have is iStream.available() which you use to create buffer and  request. available only tells you how much bytes are available, it does not tell you if your request is complete. You need some indication about how many request bytes you are going to receive or some kind of end of request character. Your request will be incomplete otherwise most of the times and so will your reponse

Comment: What is the reason for the constraints about not using `readLine()` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your answer isn't some mythical EOF character, it is that you're ignoring the read count. It should be

```
int count = in.read(buf);
if (count == -1)
    throw new EOFException();
String request = new String(buf, 0, count);`
```

Answer (score 0):

I once dealt with a similar issue. I needed to get a String using UTF-16 with bytes encoded in UTF-8. So I wrote this method to do so:

```
//NOTE: 'charsetName' has to be a valid Name (see 'Charset'-Class in the API)
public String encode(char[] data, String charsetName)
{
    //Convert char[] to a String
    String charString = String.copyValueOf(data);
    String encoded = "";

    try 
    {
        //Since there is no constructor which lets you set char[] with encoding
        //convert your String to a byte-Array. There is a constructor which lets 
        //you set the Encoding for it.
        byte[] bytesEncoded = charString.getBytes(charsetName);

        //Construct a String using the encoding
        encoded = new String(bytesEncoded, charsetName);
    } 
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return encoded;
}
```

(You'd set "UTF-16LE" as charsetName)

Looks somehow "dirty" converting data back and forth, but for me it worked perfectly.

Comment: unfortunately I am still getting some weird chars after <EOF>. but thanks for your help!.

Answer (score -1):

In the end what work for me was:

1. I am always allocating the buffer at size 1024 without using **iStream.available()** as Ata noticed.
2. After many attempts I did not figured how to escape all the chars after "EOF". I just split the received string by EOF and take the first fragment of the string, and it worked just fine. EOF symbols end of the request from the client.

This is the code I ended up using

```
private void readDataTest() throws IOException
{
    InputStream iStream = _socket.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(iStream, Charset.forName("UTF-16LE"));
    DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(_socket.getOutputStream());
    char[] buf = new char[1024];
    in.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
    String request = new String(buf);
    request = request.split(Consts.EOF)[0];

    String responseStr = parseResponse(request);
    byte[] response = responseStr.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
    outToClient.write(response);
    outToClient.flush();
    outToClient.close();
    in.close();
    _socket.close();
}
```

Comment: EOF isn't a character in the data.

Comment: yes it does, you can see I am using Consts.EOF, this string is "<EOF>" a string represents the end of the received string you can see this in the second comment on the first post.

Comment: So your code is *sending* some EOF character? Not shown anywhere.

Comment: As I said you can see this in the second comment of the first post
 
After printing what I am receiving I noticed something strange: request=BB0006<ENDL>0011<EOF>└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א└א there are many characters at the end that don't need to be there, maybe there is a problem with line char[] buf = new char[iStream.available()];